# Spring boot, перестало работать приложение ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Tags: spring, spring-boot, firewall

Есть контроллер

```
@RestController
class FileSystemController {
    Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(FileSystemController.class);

    String path = "C:/TestCatalog/test";

    @Autowired
    Path dir;

    @Autowired
    AmqpTemplate template;

    @Autowired
    DirectoryScanner dirScanner;

    @Autowired
    DirEventsWatcherService eventsWatcher;

    @RequestMapping("/file")
    public List<File> queue1() {
        return dirScanner.scanPath(path);
    }

    @RequestMapping("/sfm")
    public void startFilesMonitor() throws Exception {
        System.out.println("Monitor start");
    }
}
```

При запросе на http://localhost:8080/file
или http://localhost:8080/sfm

выдает ошибку
ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED Не удается получить доступ к сайту
Отключил файервол антивируса и windows
результат тот же
попробовал поменять порт приложения, результат тот же

Попробовал убрать один класс конфигурации AMQP

```
    package prcjt.config;

import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import org.springframework.amqp.core.*;
import org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.CachingConnectionFactory;
import org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.ConnectionFactory;
import org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitAdmin;
import org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Import;
import prcjt.fileswork.DirEventsWatcherService;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;

@Configuration
public class RabbitConfiguration {
    Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(RabbitConfiguration.class);

    String path = "C:/TestCatalog/test";
    //настраиваем соединение с RabbitMQ
    @Bean
    public ConnectionFactory connectionFactory() {
        CachingConnectionFactory connectionFactory =
                new CachingConnectionFactory("localhost");
        return connectionFactory;
    }

    @Bean
    public AmqpAdmin amqpAdmin() {
        return new RabbitAdmin(connectionFactory());
    }

    @Bean
    public RabbitTemplate rabbitTemplate() {
        return new RabbitTemplate(connectionFactory());
    }

    //объявляем очередь с именем queue1
    @Bean
    public Queue myQueue1() {
        return new Queue("queue-events");
    }

    @Bean
    public FanoutExchange fanoutExchangeA() {
        return new FanoutExchange("exchange-events");
    }

    @Bean
    public Binding binding1() {
        return BindingBuilder.bind(myQueue1()).to(fanoutExchangeA());
    }

    @Bean
    public Path dirPath(){
        return Paths.get(path);
    }
    @Bean
    public DirEventsWatcherService watcher() throws IOException {
        return new DirEventsWatcherService(dirPath(),rabbitTemplate());
    }
}
```

Без него данной проблемы нет. А с ним есть. Код офорлмен согласно примерам на оф сайте    RabbitMQ. Мб что-то не так с зависимостями?

Comment: а что в логах сервера?

Comment: Насколько я понимаю, по умолчанию Spring-Boot не использует файл для логгирования, все выводится в консоль, в консоли при запросе ничего не отображается. Как настроить отдельно логгирования томкат в спринг-бут не знаю, и сомневаюсь, что есть такая возможность

Comment: единственное, при старте приложения
2017-07-30 18:45:30.940  INFO 12364 --- [           main] s.b.c.e.t.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)

2017-07-30 18:45:30.977  INFO 12364 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service Tomcat

Comment: логирование можно настроить в **application.properties**. включите более высокий уровень и смотрите, что там происходит. вот тут подробнее https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-logging.html

Comment: а более высокий уровень, это какой?

Comment: сделал настройки как в примере, все равно не понимаю, что и где я должен увидеть

Comment: вы должны увидеть в логах информацию о загрузки вашего бина и возможно там же будут ошибки. а что вы изменили перед тем как приложение перестало работать?

Comment: дополнительно указал в самом вопросе, после конфигрурирования класса public class RabbitConfiguration, класс прикрепил к вопросу

Comment: включайте логирование и ищите ошибки в логах. либо добавьте в вопрос [mcve]